# Build GEOTiff file using Python GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff

Is there a way to add data to a GEOTiff file in a loop? I can make one using WriteArray like so:

```
dataset.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(array)
```

But whenever I put it in a for loop it just overwrites the data that was already there. I want to be able to append data to the existing data. The files this needs to work with can be too large to fit into memory so we can't do it in a single pass.

Comment: Can you build the array iteratively and write all at once at the end?

Comment: See answer below, but if you want more detail, edit your question to provide a short code sample of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I've started using [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio)'s windowed [read/write](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/docs/windowed-rw.rst)

However, you can use x and y offsets when writing your array to the output dataset.

```
dataset.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(array, xoff, yoff)
```